# How to get specific properties of array of objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code and test data:

```
const getNestedObject = (nestedObj, pathArr) => {
    return pathArr.reduce((obj, key) => {
        return (obj && obj[key] !== 'undefined') ? obj[key] : undefined, nestedObj;
    });
}

const obj = 
 [
  {
      a: 1,
      c: [
        {
          d: 1,
          e: 'string',
          f: [
            {
              value: 0,
            },
            {
              value: 1,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
  },
    {
      a: 2,
      c: [
        {
          d: 2,
          e: 'string',
          f: [
            {
              value: 3,
            },
            {
              value: 4,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
  },
 ];

console.log(obj);
const fs = obj.map(o => getNestedObject(o, ['c', 'f']));
console.log(fs);
```

What I want to do is given the array of objects shown below, I want to get only the property called `f` from every object in the array. So, basically end result should be array of `f` values of every object. Since 'f' is an array, I would highly appreciate the end result to be just one array with elements from all 'f' properties, so kind of every of these 'f' to be spread out, so I have one array. My above `getNestedObject` function does not seem to work, as when the `console.log` statement below returns the whole object. Any ideas how to do this in JS?

So basically the end result should be:

```
[{ value: 0 }, { value: 1 }, { value: 3 }, {value: 4 }]
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the case where you have `{ f: 1, g: {f : 2} }`?

Comment: this is easy with JavaScript but a one liner with lodash - is lodash ok?

Comment: @vlaz Well in my case, there is not such nested object with the same property names, and `f` is always an array in my case, but for the sake of argument, we should just get the first occurrence of `f'.

Comment: @danday74 No, I do not want to use any external package. Thanks for pointing it out. A purely JS solution would be welcome. But of course you can include that also for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Your `obj` var name is a bit misleading because it's an array, albeit with objects in it.

Comment: Are `f` properties always in the `c` object?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, it is

Comment: @ggorlen Totally agree. I started with something else, and forgot to change it. But don't want to change it now in order not to confuse the people working on a solution.

Comment: this could be -not- a good whiteboard exercise haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `reduce()` with `map()`. Basically reduce your main array into an flattened array of all the `c.f` items. This checks for the `c` property just in case the object doesn't have it:

```js
const obj = [{a: 1,c: [{d: 1,e: 'string',f: [{value: 0,},{value: 1,}],},],},{a: 2,c: [{d: 2,e: 'string',f: [{value: 3,},{value: 4,}],},],},];

let Fs = obj.reduce((arr, item) => 
    item.c
    ? arr.concat(...item.c.map(itemc => itemc.f ))  // concat for flattened rather than nested arrays
    : arr
    , []);

console.log(Fs)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work nicely. One think is that I need to flatten the arrays at the end. I made an edit to your answer, to achieve what I want.

Comment: Thanks @tinker. You can flatten the whole thing using the `...` spread operator within the `concat` call. I edited the answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fast iterative solution that won't overflow the stack, makes no assumptions about target result values being arrays (only spreads if they are) and doesn't hard-code child key names (it'll explore any values that are arrays).

This can also work if the target has children matching the key that you'd like to include in the search (swap `else if` with `if`).

```js
const get = (data, target) => {
  const result = [];
  const stack = [data];
  
  while (stack.length) {
    const curr = stack.pop();
    
    for (const o of curr) {
      for (const k in o) {
        if (k === target) {
          if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
            result.push(...o[k]);
          }
          else {
            result.push(o[k]);
          }
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
          stack.push(o[k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
};
 
const obj = 
[
  {
      a: 1,
      c: [
        {
          d: 1,
          e: 'string',
          f: [
            {
              value: 0,
            },
            {
              value: 1,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
  },
    {
      a: 2,
      c: [
        {
          d: 2,
          e: 'string',
          f: [
            {
              value: 3,
            },
            {
              value: 4,
            }
          ],
        },
      ],
  },
 ];
 
 console.log(get(obj, "f"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively traverse any objects and arrays to fetch a given property. This works at any depth and doesn't care about the structure of the objects:

```js
const obj=[{a:1,c:[{d:1,e:"string",f:[{value:0},{value:1}]}]},{a:2,c:[{d:2,e:"string",f:[{value:3},{value:4}]}]}];

//curried function to grab a property by name off some object or array
function grab(prop) {
  //naming the inner function means it can be called recursively by name
  return function recursiveGrab(target) {
    if (Array.isArray(target)) {
      const arrayResult = target
          .filter(x => typeof x === "object") //remove non-objects (and non-arrays)
          .filter(Boolean) //remove null
          .map(recursiveGrab); //recursively call for the remaining objects 
      return flatten(arrayResult); //return a single dimensional array
    }
    
    //an object has the property - return it
    if (prop in target) {
      return target[prop];
    }
    
    //object doesn't have the property - check all values
    return recursiveGrab(Object.values(target));
  }
}

//small helper function. It's separated only to keep the logic for the traversal clear
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
}

const grabF = grab('f');

console.log(grabF(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice that `f` was always inside `c`. I have this recursive and dirty looking solution that works with `f` being inside any of the fields

```js
        const objArray = [
          {
              a: 1,
              c: [
                {
                  d: 1,
                  e: 'string',
                  f: [
                    {
                      value: 0,
                    },
                    {
                      value: 1,
                    }
                  ],
                },
              ],
             d: [
                {
                  d: 1,
                  e: 'string',
                  f: [
                    {
                      value: 'd',
                    },
                    {
                      value: 'd1',
                    }
                  ],
                },
              ],
          },
            {
              a: 2,
              c: [
                {
                  d: 2,
                  e: 'string',
                  f: [
                    {
                      value: 3,
                    },
                    {
                      value: 4,
                    }
                  ],
                },
              ],
              e: [
                {
                  d: 1,
                  e: 'string',
                  f: [
                    {
                      value: 'e',
                    },
                    {
                      value: 'e1',
                    }
                  ],
                },
              ],
            }
        ]
         
         
         const getFObject = (obj) => {
           let fObj = [];
           Object.keys(obj).some(key => {
             if (key === 'f') {
               fObj = obj[key];
               return true;
             }
             if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
               obj[key].forEach(nestedObj => {
                 fObj = fObj.concat(getFObject(nestedObj))
               });
             }
             return false;
           });
           return fObj;
         }
         
         const newArray = objArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
           return acc.concat(getFObject(obj))
         }, []);
         console.log(newArray)
```