# JavaScript find Object Property

Tags: javascript

I want to find the attributes I want inside the object.
There is one object.

```
let obj = {
  1: {
    2 : {
      3: {
        4: {
          5: {

          }
        }
      },
      100: {

      }
    }
  },
  6: {
    7: {
      8: {
      }
    },
    14:{

    }
  },
  11: {
    12: {

    },
    13:{

    }
  }
}
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(1)); // true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(6)); // true
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(2)); // false
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(3)); // false
```

I want to get true results when I search with 2(others).

What should I do?

Comment: I wrote something similar for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541096/how-to-get-specific-properties-of-array-of-objects-in-js) - it and the other answers might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a recursive function. One option is to test whether `some` of the `entries` either have the property you're looking for, or if the entry's value is an object, and that object passes the recursive test:

```js
let obj={1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{}}},100:{}}},6:{7:{8:{}},14:{}},11:{12:{},13:{}}}

function hasNestedProp(obj, findProp) {
  findProp = String(findProp);
  return Object.entries(obj).some(([key, val]) => {
    return (
      key === findProp
      || typeof val === 'object' && hasNestedProp(val, findProp)
    );
  });
}

console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, 1));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, 6));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, 2));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, 3));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, 555));
```

Or, more concisely, if you pass in string values instead (properties are always *strings*, after all):

```js
let obj={1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{}}},100:{}}},6:{7:{8:{}},14:{}},11:{12:{},13:{}}}

const hasNestedProp = (obj, findProp) => (
  Object.entries(obj).some(([key, val]) => (
    key === findProp
    || typeof val === 'object' && hasNestedProp(val, findProp)
  ))
)

console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, '1'));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, '6'));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, '2'));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, '3'));
console.log(hasNestedProp(obj, '555'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For nested object, you will need to check for each sub-object as well. Try following

```js
let obj={1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{}}},100:{}}},6:{7:{8:{}},14:{}},11:{12:{},13:{}}}

function hasKey(o, key) {
  for(let k in o) {
    if(k == key) return true;
    else if(typeof o[k] === "object" && hasKey(o[k], key)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasKey(obj, 1)); // true
console.log(hasKey(obj, 6)); // true
console.log(hasKey(obj, 2)); // true
console.log(hasKey(obj, 3)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

you might consider [loadash _.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) as an option. the following is their example:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const obj = {1:{2:{3:{4:{5:{}}},100:{}}},6:{7:{8:{}},14:{}},11:{12:{},13:{}}};
const hasKey = (obj, key) => Object
  .keys(obj)
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c == key || typeof obj[c] === 'object' && hasKey(obj[c], key)) {
      a = true;
    }
    return a;
  }, false);

console.log(hasKey(obj, 1));
console.log(hasKey(obj, 6));
console.log(hasKey(obj, 2));
console.log(hasKey(obj, 3));
console.log(hasKey(obj, 555));
```